# Solve $\int \frac{x^4+x^8}{(1-x^4)^{\frac{7}{2}}} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Solve $\int \dfrac{x^4+x^8}{(1-x^4)^{\frac{7}{2}}} \, dx$

My attempt is as follows:-

$$1-x^4=t$$
$$-4x^3=\dfrac{dt}{dx}$$
$$x^3dx=\dfrac{-dt}{4}$$

$$\frac{-1}{4}\cdot\int\dfrac{(1-t)^{\frac{1}{4}}(1-t)}{t^{\frac{7}{2}}}dt$$
$$\frac{-1}{4}\cdot\int\dfrac{(1-t)^\frac{5}{4}}{t^{\frac{7}{2}}}dt$$
$$\frac{-1}{4}\cdot\int\left(\dfrac{1}{t} -1\right)^{\frac{5}{4}}\cdot\left(\dfrac{1}{t} \right)^{\frac{9}{4}}dt$$

$$\frac{-1}{4}\cdot\int\left(\dfrac{1}{t} -1\right)^{\frac{5}{4}}\cdot\left(\dfrac{1}{t} \right)^2\cdot\left(\dfrac{1}{t}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}} \, dt$$

$$\frac{1}{t}-1=y$$
$$\frac{-1}{t^2}=\frac{dy}{dt}$$
$$\frac{dt}{t^2}=-dy$$

$$\frac{1}{4}\int y^\frac{5}{4}(y+1)^{\frac{1}{4}} \, dy$$
$$\frac{1}{4}\int y(y^2+y)^{\frac{1}{4}} \, dy$$
$$\frac{1}{8}\int (2y+1-1)(y^2+y)^{\frac{1}{4}} \, dy$$
$$\frac{1}{8}\left(\int (2y+1)(y^2+y)^{\frac{1}{4}} \, dy-\int (y^2+y)^{\frac{1}{4}} \, dy\right)$$
$$\frac{1}{8}\left(\int (2y+1)(y^2+y)^{\frac{1}{4}} \, dy - \int\left(\left(y+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\right)^\frac{1}{4} \right)$$

How to proceed from here or feel free to suggest some shorter and clean way.

**Another way recommended**

$$I=I_1+I_2$$
$$I=\int \dfrac{x^4}{(1-x^4)^{\frac{7}{2}}}dx+\int \dfrac{x^8}{(1-x^4)^{\frac{7}{2}}}dx$$

First let's solve $I_2$

$$I_2=\int x^5\left(\dfrac{x^3}{(1-x^4)^{\frac{7}{2}}}\right)dx$$

Integrating by parts:-

$$I_2=\dfrac{1}{10}\cdot\dfrac{x^5}{(1-x^4)^{\frac{5}{2}}}-\dfrac{1}{10}\cdot\int \dfrac{5x^4}{(1-x^4)^{\frac{5}{2}}}dx$$

$$I_2=\dfrac{1}{10}\cdot\dfrac{x^5}{(1-x^4)^{\frac{5}{2}}}-\dfrac{1}{10}\cdot\int \dfrac{5x^4(1-x^4)}{(1-x^4)^{\frac{7}{2}}}dx$$

$$I_2=\dfrac{1}{10}\cdot\dfrac{x^5}{(1-x^4)^{\frac{5}{2}}}-\dfrac{1}{10}\cdot\int \dfrac{5x^4(1-x^4)}{(1-x^4)^{\frac{7}{2}}}dx$$

$$I_2=\dfrac{1}{10}\cdot\dfrac{x^5}{(1-x^4)^{\frac{5}{2}}}-\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\int \dfrac{x^4}{(1-x^4)^{\frac{7}{2}}}dx+\dfrac{I_2}{2}$$

$$\dfrac{I_2}{2}+\dfrac{I_1}{2}=\dfrac{1}{10}\cdot\dfrac{x^5}{(1-x^4)^{\frac{5}{2}}}$$

$$I_1+I_2=\dfrac{1}{5}\cdot\dfrac{x^5}{(1-x^4)^{\frac{5}{2}}}$$
$$I=\dfrac{1}{5}\cdot\dfrac{x^5}{(1-x^4)^{\frac{5}{2}}}$$

Comment: if $t = 1-x^4$ shouldn't the numerator be $(1-t) + (1-t)^4$?

Comment: @qwr You are probably forgetting the $\mathrm dx$ factor.

Comment: $x^3$ went in derivative, so what remained was $x(1+x^4)$

Comment: "Solve" is the wrong word here. One _solves_ equations; one _solves_ problems. One _evaluates_ expressions, and that is what one has here.

Answer (score 7):

It is often easier to look for what form the antiderivative would be and differentiating that when dealing with messy rational functions.

Use the quotient rule to see that we have:

\begin{align}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\frac{f(x)}{(1-x^4)^{5/2}}&=\frac{(1-x^4)^{5/2}f'(x)+10x^3(1-x^4)^{3/2}f(x)}{(1-x^4)^5}\\&=\frac{(1-x^4)f'(x)+10x^3f(x)}{(1-x^4)^{7/2}}\end{align}

We seek to then solve

$$x^4+x^8=(1-x^4)f'(x)+10x^3f(x)$$

It is easy to verify that we then have $f(x)=x^5/5$ by substituting in a polynomial of degree $5$ to match the power on the LHS. Hence we conclude:

$$\int\frac{x^4+x^8}{(1-x^4)^{7/2}}~\mathrm dx=\frac{x^5}{5(1-x^4)^{5/2}}+C$$

Comment: power in denominator is $\frac{7}{2}$, not $\frac{5}{2}$

Comment: Sorry, typos.${}$

Comment: can you correct your latex?

Comment: @Ducan, what is the advantage?

Comment: how did you get the idea of differentiating $f(x)$ with $(1-x^4)^{\frac{5}{2}}$

Comment: It is apparent that when differentiating such a rational function, the "degree" of the denominator increases by 1.

Comment: but if we are expected to get the result by solving the integration, then?

Comment: @user3290550 Integration by parts combined with chain rule, where you handle a part of the integral using $u=(1-x^4)^{5/2}$. In essence, reversed quotient rule (which is product rule and chain rule applied to $f(x)[g(x)]^{-1}$.)

Answer (score 2):

Let $t=\frac x{\sqrt{1-x^4}}$ and $dt = \frac{1+x^4}{(1-x^4)^{3/2}}dx$

$$\int \dfrac{x^4+x^8}{(1-x^4)^{7/2}} dx
=\int t^4dt = \frac15t^5+C$$

Comment: Intriguing approach.  My *bible* is Calculus (volumes 1 and 2) by Apostol, which does not contain any guidance for adopting your approach as a **first try** (i.e. it does, for example, advocate attacking $\int R(x, \sqrt{a^2 - [cx + d]^2})dx$ via $cx+d = a \sin t$.  Is there a calculus textbook that explores problems similar to the one queried here, advocating customized approaches for each such problem?

Comment: Integrals such as this one barely have any practical significance. They are customarily designed to explore ‘perfect’ substitution identified here. They are many of kinds for which the textbook techniques for integration are ineffective. Another example is $\int \frac1{(1+x)\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=-2\sqrt t$, where the perfect substitute is $t=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$

Answer (score 0):

As $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{x^3}{(1-x^4)^m}dx=\dfrac1{4(m-1)(1-x^4)^{m-1}},$

$$I(m,n)=\int\dfrac{x^{4n-3}\cdot x^3}{(1-x^4)^m}dx=x^{4n-3}\int\dfrac{x^3}{(1-x^4)^m}dx-\int\left(\dfrac{d(x^{4n-3})}{dx}\int\dfrac{x^3}{(1-x^4)^m}dx\right)dx$$

$$=\dfrac{x^{4n-3}}{4(m-1)(1-x^4)^{m-1}}-(4n-3)\int\dfrac{x^{4n-4}}{4(m-1)(1-x^4)^{m-1}}dx$$

$$=\dfrac{x^{4n-3}}{4(m-1)(1-x^4)^{m-1}}-\dfrac{4n-3}{4(m-1)}\int\dfrac{x^{4n-4}(1-x^4)}{(1-x^4)^m}dx$$

$$\implies I(m,n)\left(1-\dfrac{4n-3}{4(m-1)}\right)+\dfrac{4n-3}{4(m-1)}\cdot I(m,n-1)=\dfrac{x^{4n-3}}{4(m-1)(1-x^4)^{m-1}}$$

Set $1-\dfrac{4n-3}{4(m-1)}=\dfrac{4n-3}{4(m-1)}\iff 4n=2m+1$

$$\implies\dfrac12\left(I\left(m,\dfrac{2m+1}4\right) +  I\left(m,\dfrac{2m-3}4\right)\right)=\dfrac{x^{2m+1-3}}{4(m-1)(1-x^4)^{m-1}}$$

Finally set $n=2\iff2m=7$

Comment: First of all $$m\ne-1$$  and  we can different values of $n$ to generate many such integral problems. For example set $2m+1=4\cdot3$